# Do files uploaded count against your site collection quota if using remote blob storage?

Tags: external-blob-storage

There is a debate going on in my group as we plan to use SharePoint 2010.  We want to use Remote Blob Storage (RBS) instead of storing files in the SQL tables themselves.  If we use RBS, do the files people upload still count against their site collection quota?

To me, it seems obvious that they would.  To others in my group, it seems obvious that it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience it does, you also have the 2GB file limit as well which sucks

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it counts in WSS 3.0 as RBS is just another means of storage. Site collection quotas are another the storage mechanism. They could have changed this for 2010, but it doubt it given the fundamental nature of it. Also this seems to agree with what I am thinking:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx

Remote BLOB Storage (RBS) is an add-on feature pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2008. RBS is designed to move the storage of binary large objects (BLOBs) from database servers to commodity storage solutions. If the content databases in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 are 4 gigabytes (GB) or larger, consider using RBS as part of your data storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

EBS or RBS have no impact on how SharePoint calculates quotas.

Regarding the 2GB file limit mentioned by Michal, the SharePoint OM and DM both impose a 2GB limit on the BLOB size.  You can actually trick the OM into accepting a document larger than 2GB, but the Size attribute for that document in the content database would then be represented as a negative integer from any content greater in size than 2GB and up to 4GB, which would obviously cause the retrieval of that content to fail.